# Change the legend of a Matlab figure

Tags: matlab

I would like to change the legend style of the following picture generated in Matlab:

```
x1=-5;
x2=5;
y1=-5;
y2=5;
x = [x1, x2, x2, x1, x1];
y = [y1, y1, y2, y2, y1];
fill(x,y,'b')
legend('A')
```

[image]

As you can see the legend displays a blue rectangle. What I would like is a **filled blue circle** in place of the rectangle **as if the picture was generated as a scatter plot**. How can I obtain that?

Comment: The answers that you got are good, but you might also want to take a look at [`legtools`](https://github.com/StackOverflowMATLABchat/legtools).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to add a fictive value with `hold on; p = plot(NaN, NaN, 'b.', 'MarkerSize', 15);` then legend this specific "fake" plot with: `legend(p, 'A');`

```
x1=-5;
x2=5;
y1=-5;
y2=5;
x = [x1, x2, x2, x1, x1];
y = [y1, y1, y2, y2, y1];
fill(x,y,'b');
hold on; p = plot(NaN, NaN, 'b.', 'MarkerSize', 15);
legend(p, 'A')
```

[image: fill and legend]

Answer (score 3):

@Bebs has a nice solution.

Another suggest is to change directly the legend icon:

```
[a,b] = legend('A');
b(2).Xdata = sin(-pi:0.1:pi)/10+0.4;   % you can play with numbers to set size and location of circle
b(2).Ydata = cos(-pi:0.1:pi)/5+0.5;
```

Now you can set some other properties:

```
b(2).LineWidth = 1;         % thicker line
b(2).FaceColor = [1 1 1];   % white fill
b(2).EdgeColor = [0 0 1];   % blue edge
```

[image]